# RequireJS - Loading an already loaded module

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I am trying to use [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/) to load browser modules and I came into an interesting problem.

I have 3 modules named `a`, `b` and `c` having these simple source code:

#### a.js

```
define(['./b', './c'], function(c, b) {
 console.log('A IS LOADED!');

 return 'A';
});
```

#### b.js

```
define(function() {
 console.log('B IS LOADED!');

 return 'B';
});
```

#### c.js

```
define(function() {
 console.log('C IS LOADED!');

 return 'C';
});
```

---

When I load module `a` by itself, everything is working just fine, the following code runs and returns 'A':

```
require(['./a'], function(a) { 
    console.log(a); // 'A'
});
```

But if I need two different modules, which one of was already loaded:

```
require(['./a', './c'], function(a, c) { 
    console.log(a, c);
});
```

RequireJS will error:

```
C IS LOADED!
B IS LOADED!
require.js load timeout for modules: ./c
```

when it's obviously already loaded.

Has anyone encountered this issue before? How can I solve it?

Comment: Are you testing this through `file://` or `http://`? If it's HTTP, have you checked Firebug etc. to see what the browser is doing?

Comment: HTTP, and file isn't being loaded at all. (No extra .js on net tab).

Comment: This was also asked on the RequireJS list, and [there is a response is in this thread](http://groups.google.com/group/requirejs/browse_thread/thread/6eda8c948bae9d49).

Answer (score 0):

According to the RequireJS website (http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#timeout) :

Likely causes and fixes:

- There was a script error in one of the listed modules. If there is no script error in the browser's error console, and if you are using
  Firebug, try loading the page in another browser like Chrome or
  Safari. Sometimes script errors do not show up in Firebug.
- The path configuration for a module is incorrect. Check the "Net" or "Network" tab in the browser's developer tools to see if there was
  a 404 for an URL that would map to the module name. Make sure the
  script file is in the right place. In some cases you may need to use
  the paths configuration to fix the URL resolution for the script.

Comment: it is already specified in documentation. Error throw message.